# Xvfb PyQt5 Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display

Tags: python, qt, jenkins, xvfb, pyqt5

I;m trying to run untitests for my PyQt5 application on Jenkins.

I've setup job and configure Xvfb with option `+extension RANDR`

Here is output of starting Xvfb:

```
Xvfb starting$ Xvfb -displayfd 2 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 -fbdir /var/lib/jenkins/2014-08-27_00-24-501722001619127938033xvfb +extension RANDR
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension DRI3
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension GLX
1
```

But my gui tests fail with `Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".`

How can I fix this? Is there any other way to run PyQt5 GUI unittest?

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644001/how-to-add-the-missing-randr-extension) question, but it didn't help

I'm using ubuntu 14.04.1 x86_64; python3.4

Comment: error if for display `:1` and your shell command is for `fd 2` and `screen 0`, is there perhaps a mismatch here?

Comment: No, I've tried to start test with manual start Xvfb with default parameters plus RANDR exception and get the same error on display :99

Comment: What is value of `DISPLAY` when you run the unit tests? Does the order of parameters to `Xvfb` matter? That `SocketCreateListener() failed` error, perhaps there's another X server running already or something?