# How to start a wide browser inside a docker container, for Protractor testing

Tags: docker, protractor, xvfb

When running end to end tests inside a docker container we need the browser to be wide, to make sure the elements (aButton) that are positioned far right are actually visible and test like

```
expect(mainPage.aButton.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

succeed.

When displaying the browser width we always get a value close to 1050 as a maximum:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().getSize().then(function(size) {
    console.log('browser size', size);
});
```

displays:

```
browser size { height: 748,
               width: 1050,
               class: 'org.openqa.selenium.Dimension',
               hCode: 436207616 }
```

When using this two docker images to run the tests against they fail because the button is not visible. When running the test on the browser not inside Docker/Xvfb there is no problem.

https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/caltha/protractor/

Modified the settings of the Xvfb config by linking a local version like this (and some log folders for debugging..)

```
mkdir -p /tmp/docker/protractor/supervisor
docker run --rm  \
--name run_protractor \
-v /tmp/docker/protractor:/var/log \
-v /tmp/testproject:/project \  
-v /tmp/xvfb.conf:/etc/supervisor/conf.d/xvfb.conf:ro \
caltha/protractor
```

the file for the Xvfb settings xvfb.conf:

```
[program:xvfb]
command = Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1920x1080x16
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s-out.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s-err.log
```

When running the same test on this docker image we also get a 'small' browser:

http://www.function.fr/docker-with-chrome-and-selenium-and-firefox/

some more info: 
We start all our 'stuff' in linked Docker containers for Integration / End to end testing, a database container, tomcat/rest/java container for server.
and a npm container for the angular website.

protractor.conf.js:

```
....
onPrepare: function() {    
  browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
  //var width = 1224;
  //var height = 800;
  //browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
}
```

How do we get a wide browser?
(we don't use a responsive design for our website obviously)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your docker-compose.yml file:

```
chrome:
  image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
  environment:
    SCREEN_WIDTH: 1920
    SCREEN_HEIGHT: 1080
  ports:
    - 5900
  links:
    - seleniumhub:hub
```

If you're using a debug node, you're done. If you're not, never fear! Maximize won't work, but `driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));` will.

Comment: I am not so sure about the last  part of the answer since it appears to be WebDriverJS syntax. But the part about changing the docker image to pull node-chrome-debug and setting the environmental variables definitely worked for me.

Comment: It's Java syntax, using WebDriver 2.53.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your issue is in Docker, Protractor, or xvfb... but on the Protractor side, I would try setting a specific browser size. I.E. beyond the size `maximize()` would likely provide.

So try setting the following in your Protractor config onPrepare:

```
browser.manage().window().setSize(2024, 800); // or whatever
```

This *should* give you a wide browser... not sure if it will pass your tests though.

I might also try [changing 'xvfb's resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356169/resizing-an-xvfb-display)...

Comment: thanks for your reply. we tryed both solutions: in config onPrepare browser.driver.manage().window().maximize(); or browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height); and xvfb via a config file /etc/supervisor/conf.d/xvfb.conf as mentioned above. none worked inside the docker container ...

Comment: @JanvO did you manage to get it working ? Even I'm facing same issue. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/220